# How to set the cell color in a UITableView to transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with several sections of static cells all setup in my storyboard file.

My question is: How do I set the color of one of the cells to be transparent? 
I have tried going to the inspector with the cell selected under view> background and set it to >Clear color, but doing this give the cell a "clear" color but the borders of the cell are still visible :
[image],

can someone please help me achieve this without the borders? Thanks

****Edit**** I have tried setting the alpha level to 0 but this does not seem to have an impact.

I have also tried to implement the following but I get the same result as picture above:

```
_topCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I have also tried to implement :

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and got the following result:

[image]

Please ignore the vertical line that divides the title from the description, that is simply a `UIImageView` with a vertical line image.

Just to give you guys an idea, I am doing this because ultimately I am looking for a clear / clean cell to add some round rect buttons to for example the "Text Message","Share Contact" & "Add to favorites" buttons shown below:

[image]

Comment: This is not directly related, but from what I read, the use of transparent color greatly slows down the scroll speed. This may no longer be the case, but under iOS 5 the table view would become barely usable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I appreciate the advice, I'll take a look and see if the scroll is significantly slowed than it will absolutely need a replacement, thanks again!

Comment: You really ought to clean up this question for posterity's sake. You've accepted an answer that has nothing to do with the question asked in the title.

Comment: @TimothyMoose the answer I accepted gives me and other readers a cleaner / more appropriate way to achieve the results I was searching for, your answer was great nevertheless.

Comment: Agreed. Just suggesting that you reword the question to match the answer.

Comment: @TimothyMoose you are completely right, updated correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];//optional
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

The line commented "optional" is only required when you're setting a custom table background color with a pattern image (as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506533/ios-grouped-tableview-transparent-cells/17507506#17507506)).

Of course, if you only want to apply this to specific cells, you'll need to put these statements in an `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved something similar, simply abusing sections and section footers. Use sections for each important set of rows that should be grouped together (that's the point of the cell style "grouped")

For example, you can make an enum to keep track of them:

```
enum Sections
{
    SectionName,
    SectionPhone,
    SectionAddress,
    // etc...
    SectionCount
};
```

Then, use these sections as normally:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return SectionCount;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == SectionName)
    {
        return 2; // First name, last name
    }
    else if (section == SectionPhone)
    {
        return 1; // Just his phone number
    }
    else if (section == SectionAddress)
    {
        return 4; // Country, State, Street, Number
    }
    // etc...
}
```

And to have the "actions", you could add the actions related to a particular section, then simply add the two methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 52;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Only the Address has action buttons, for example
    if (section != SectionAddress)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button1 setTitle:@"Action 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Action 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setTitle:@"Action 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button1.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 96, 44);
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(button1.frame.origin.x + button1.frame.size.width + 8, 8, 96, 44);
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(button2.frame.origin.x + button1.frame.size.width + 8, 8, 96, 44);

    [view addSubview:button1];
    [view addSubview:button2];
    [view addSubview:button3];

    return view;
}
```

To return a view that has the independent buttons.

[image: preview]

Comment: I have tried implementing this and got a better result not quite what I am looking for, I have updated the question to explain. @Can

Comment: Interesting approach, would you mind explaining with a little more detail? Thanks @Can

Comment: (Updated the answer), but it's nothing really, it's just using the proper UITableViewDelegate methods accordingly to imitate the contact page. If you've noticed, the tableView style is named "Grouped" for a reason, each grouped of rows is grouped into a section, and that's what the contact page is using. Action buttons can be a separate view returned as a footer for the last row.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I do have a small question : I am new to working with UITableView's so I am not too experienced. I noticed that you are using enumerations to track the sections, I am not experienced using enumerations, I tried adding an outlet from my storyboard to my implementation, after the connection was made I received an immediate error from xcode alerting me that "Unknown type name "UITableViewSection", any suggestions for me there? Thanks @Can

Comment: `enum` is a C feature, it's just for having an easy mapping from numbers to words. For instance, instead of having `movewithAnimation:3` where 3 is "slide from bottom", they give each attribute a mapping with the name, like "UIViewAnimateFromBottom", it's more human readable that way, and apple does it all the time. You can simply use `if (section == 0) {` as normally, without any problem, the section enum is just for convenience in the example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33603/discussion-between-vzm-and-can)

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.35];
```

Comment: Actually, I had tried this already but it does not seem to effect the cell at all to set the alpha to 0 per say @Abdullah Shafique